# Improve Jquery autocomplete combobox search result

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am not saying that jquery autocomplete plugin is improper but i need improved search result in it like when i type l, it must show results that starts with l( not those which has l).Is there a way to do this.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: listen to `search` event and remove the unwanted list values

Comment: check the `_source` method in [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) example

Comment: @CerlinBoss thanks , i found the answer, just changed this                     var matcher = new RegExp( "^"+ $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );